# Buffer Memory Drops to Zero

Tags: memory, buffer

We have been having problems with a system that becomes inaccessible.  Characteristics are 1) sudden spike in blocked and run queues and 2) buffer memory drops to zero.

The symptoms are 1) existing processes continue to operate without any issues and 2) new processes begin to fail or are severely delayed.  Thus, a new SSH session, for example, may not engage because the successive processes and threads of SSH and PAM are delayed or non-responsive.  Another example are scripts generated in CRON.  With buffer memory at 0, new CRON cycles are blocked, resulting in cascading scripts.

I would assume that new processes being blocked would have something to do with stack memory.  But the symptom I am reading is a sudden drop in buffer memory (which has more to do with I/O).

Possibly connected are the Snapshot sessions.  We noticed that Snapshot dynamically mounts NFS volumes to collect backup files.  Would this possibly overwhelm available buffer capacity?

Added 08/11/2020

Not sure if this is an "answer", but it does begin to clarify the problem.  We discovered there was a Puppet script that was running every 30 minutes which was chasing down a Snapshot process.  Snapshot essentially replicates a directory tree during the backup process, so you can well imagine that an innocent df command embedded in a script could turn into a tyrant, busily compiling an entire tree of data.  We noticed that df commands were frequently appearing and cascading because the Puppet script was not completing and simply stacking upon itself each time it was called up in cron.

System became a great deal more stable after we removed the Puppet process.  But we had another spike in blocked processes this morning -- so stay tuned.  This mystery  may not be solved as of yet.

Comment: This is a ... raspberry pi zero?

Comment: If you can, run `dmesg -T | grep drop_caches` after that happens and check the timestamps. Maybe some application deletes the buffer (metadata) cache.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion regarding dmesg.

Comment: This metric may help.  From sar -R (swap memory)

10:30:01 AM    -23.26      0.00   -484.54
10:40:01 AM     -9.91      0.00   -354.41
10:50:18 AM     19.16     -0.04  -3987.68
11:00:01 AM   3240.54      0.00    780.13
11:10:01 AM  -3099.08      0.04   2997.32
11:20:01 AM    -24.36      0.00    167.64
11:30:01 AM    -17.78      0.00   -577.39
11:40:01 AM      9.24      0.00    153.16
11:50:01 AM     35.59      0.00     97.64
12:00:02 PM     -2.25      0.00   -758.18

12:00:02 PM   frmpg/s   bufpg/s   campg/s